# "Failed to transform class with name" error when mocking a class with a static enum class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, powermock

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name com.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX$ReadSets. Reason: null
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:219)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:147)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:67)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:390)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(AnnotationParser.java:371)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:673)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:480)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:306)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:241)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:70)
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3089)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:3069)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.classAnnotations(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:163)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.getDescription(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:155)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.getDescription(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:171)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.getDescription(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.sendTree(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.sendTrees(RemoteTestRunner.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupMethod(MemberResolver.java:110)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupMethod(MemberResolver.java:96)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMethodCallCore(TypeChecker.java:704)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:681)
    at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:156)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:45)
    at javassist.compiler.Javac$1.setReturnType(Javac.java:449)
    at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:146)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:45)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atVariableAssign(TypeChecker.java:248)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atAssignExpr(TypeChecker.java:217)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.AssignExpr.accept(AssignExpr.java:38)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:235)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:323)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:49)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:344)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:49)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atIfStmnt(CodeGen.java:384)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:348)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:49)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:344)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:49)
    at javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:558)
    at javassist.expr.MethodCall.replace(MethodCall.java:233)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer$PowerMockExpressionEditor.edit(MainMockTransformer.java:299)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.loopBody(ExprEditor.java:178)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.doit(ExprEditor.java:90)
    at javassist.CtClassType.instrument(CtClassType.java:1224)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.transform(MainMockTransformer.java:75)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:215)
    ... 28 more
```

This class contains a static method getInstance (which i want to mock), to provide a singleton object and a couple of Enum classes declared as public static (one of them named ReadSets is seen in the exception). Below is how the class looks like.

Am trying to mock this class in my test method using PowerMockito.mock and Powermockito.MockStatic and it throws the exception.

Any clues on how it can be fixed?

```
public class XXX extends YYY {

    private volatile static XXX s_instance;

    public static XXX getInstance() {
        if (s_instance == null)
            synchronized (XXX.class) {
                if (s_instance == null)
                    s_instance = new XXX();
            }
        return s_instance;
    }

    public static enum ReadSets {
        ANY(1), ALL(2);
        int val;

        public int getVal() {
            return val;
        }

        private ReadSets(int v) {
            val = v;
        }
    }

    public static enum UpdateSets {
        ANY(1), ALL(2);
        int val;

        private UpdateSets(int v) {
            val = v;
        }
    }

    // [...]

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in one of my tests, for me it was cause by conflicting versions of javassist.
Some dependency use javassist.javassist-3.4.GA while PowerMock used org.javassist.javassist-3.18.1-GA (the **org.** is the main difference).
It seems that eclipse put the former one into the classpath first, so the older version was used.

I use maven, so I could solve the conflict by creating an exclusion-rule for javassist.javassist within the dependency that pulled it and depend on a newer jassist version directly. Not the nicest soltution, but I don't know a better way to handle these artefact-moves in maven.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>some</groupId>
  <artifactId>dependency</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javassist</groupId>
      <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
  <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
  <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Of course you have to check if the dependency still works with that version.

Comment: Thanks! 
Question: Why add a separate dependency when you already added an exclusion? Wouldn't PowerMock automatically get the required version of javassist? Doesn't adding dependency separately conflict with the version PowerMock already gets (unless they are the same)?

Comment: @A.D: Yeah, you're totally right. My excuse is that I was 6 years younger! :-D All jokes aside I don't see any real reason anymore why we did include it explicitly back then. To use a newer version I would use dependencyManagement instead - and that was not part of the question.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue and referred to the answer here. It turns out that Boris is correct. PowerMock is bringing in javassist with version 3.18.2-GA which causes some things to misbehave. In my case certain unit tests started failing only when I tried to build the entire project.

I added the following dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.GA</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This way Powermock was happy with its own javassist (org.javassist) and tests were happy with the new javassist 3.4.GA.

However, I am not sure what caused the tests to fail in the first place and only when I built the entire project.